# Render partial from controller and from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render, partials

In my Rails app, I get to render an erb file from a controller and from another erb file like so:

```
# a_controller.rb
class AController < ApplicationController
def index
    render 'lista'
end

# b_controller.rb
class BController < ApplicationController
def index
    render 'listb'
end

# lista.html.erb
<%= render 'list' %>

# listb.html.erb
Some content that I want to keep
<%= render 'list' %>

# _list.html.erb
Hello
```

As you can see lista is only rendering the partial `_list`.
What I wanted to do was to call `<%= render 'lista' %>` from within `listb.html.erb`.
But when I do so, I get an error message saying that the partial `_lista` is not found.

Do you have an ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lista.html.erb` is a page, not a partial. Your code is looking for a partial called `lista` but it does not exist.

I really think you should create a new partial called `_lista`, you can render it in `lista.html.erb` and `listb.html.erb`. Your controller can still `render 'lista'` which will render the partial `_lista`.

Comment: all my files are in the `application` folder, I've seen that this way they would be accessible without specifying the folder ...

Comment: Actually, `lista` is not a partial. You are thinking of your page `lista.html.erb`. That is why you are getting the error. I updated my answer.

Comment: yes those 3, because I use them at differents places

Comment: Hey @Nobe4, cool, I updated my answer. `lista` is not a partial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78296/discussion-between-adrianmann-and-nobe4).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `_list.html.erb` **partial** (any file name) file for access it with in `lista.html.erb` or `listb.html.erb` after that you can access as you want.

For example:-

```
# lista.html.erb
<%= render 'listb' %>
```

In `lista.html.erb` we can call `listb` (*_listb.html.erb*) file that are in current directory.

Answer (score 1):

you should create a partial with name **_lista.html.erb** or you can change your file name from **lista.html.erb** to **_lista.html.erb**.

currently file lista.html.erb is not a partial that's why when you try to render **lista** partial, rails produce a error for you

```
#lista.html.erb
##assuming list is in lista/list.html.erb 
<%= render 'lista/list' %>
```

Comment: if I want to keep the pages and not the partials, can I render them from a view ?

Comment: I don't think that you can do it in this way as you said. you should use partial to render data in rails according to rails norm.